# Java Interface Contracts Issue

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-construction, interface, abstract-class

I am having an interface called **I**. This interface is implemented by an abstract class AClazz.

```
AClazz implements I
```

Now this abstract class is extended by several concrete classes.

```
ConcreteClazz extends AClazz
AnotherConcreteClazz extends AClazz
```

Now when I add a new method contract to the interface **I** why does eclipse and hence Java language complain about a missing implementation inside the concrete classes (**ConcreteClazz** and **AnotherConcreteClazz**) and not inside the abstract class AClazz?

If **AClazz** was a concrete class (& not abstract) and the concrete classes extended from the non abstract **AClazz** will Java complain about missing implementation inside concrete classes again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So say your interface `I` has a method `m`:

```
public interface I {
     public void m (int someParameter);
}
```

Now `AClazz` implements `I`, and `ConcreteClazz` extends `AClazz`.  That means that `ConcreteClazz` also implements `I`, whether or not you say so explicitly in the `class` declaration of `ConcreteClazz`.  That means you can use a `ConcreteClazz` object anywhere an `I` is expected.  So say somewhere, in some other class, you have a method

```
void takeSomeAction(Something x, I y) {
    ....
    y.m (x.getSomeProperty());  // call the interface method
    ....
}
```

You can call it with a `ConcreteClazz` object:

```
ConcreteClazz z = new ConcreteClazz(...);
Something st;

foo.takeSomeAction(st, z);
```

You're giving `takeSomeAction` a `ConcreteClazz` to use as its `I` parameter.  Then `takeSomeAction` will call the `m` method.  How can this work unless you've provided an implementation for `m`, somewhere?

That's why you need to implement `m`, either in `AClazz` or `ConcreteClazz`.  You *could* implement it in `AClazz`, if that's the right thing to do, and then you don't need to provide another implementation in `ConcreteClazz`.  But if you don't implement it in `AClazz`, it won't cause any errors, since, at runtime, you can't actually have an object of type `AClazz`.  But since you *can* have objects of type `ConcreteClazz`, that means that somewhere, for `ConcreteClazz`, there has to be an implementation of `m`.

Comment: Yep thanks I got that part. Now I am curious to know where the error would be thrown had AClazz been a concrete class instead of an abstact class. Will Java complain of missing implementation inside AClazz or inside ConcreteClazz?

Comment: @AnupSaumithri In `AClazz`.  If `AClazz` is were a concrete class, it would have to implement all the methods in `I`, or else the compiler will dipslay an error.  If `ConcreteClazz` then extends `AClazz`, I'm not sure if the compiler could even start compiling `ConcreteClazz` if `AClazz` didn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

An `Abstract class means, this class contains abstract methods (i.e. no implementation, only definition of method), the classes that are extending it must implement the unimplemented methods`.

Since an `Interface contains 100% pure public abstract methods`, which `must be implemented by the classes that are implementing` them unless it's marked as `abstract`. Again follow the above rule.

Comment: Great thank you. Its a pretty novice question, looks like Im getting out of form.

Comment: Backticks are for inline code blocks; they [shouldn't be used for emphasis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135113/232145). It would be better to use the asterisk (italics), or double asterisks (bold) instead.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class remains abstract no matter how many new abstract methods you add to it. So compiler does not complain when you add a new method in your I interface which is implemented by your abstract class.

A concrete class cannot have any abstract methods, as your subclasses are extending your abstract class and that class does not implement the newly added method to the interface, hence the compiler complains. Because newly added abstract method is inherited in all your child classes and a concrete class cannot have an abstract method.

Comment: So what if that abstract class were to be a concrete class. Is the implementation required inside the last subclasses or the immediate implementer?

Comment: @AnupSaumithri If you add the implementation for new interface method in your parent abstract class then nothing needed to be done in your child classes.

Comment: I want to know what if that parent abstract class were to be a concrete class. Where would the java complain about the missing implementation? Inside the parent concrete class or the children concrete class? Thanks'

Comment: Parent class is abstract so no complain, concrete subclasses will not be compiled.